# How to get the model/schema name from subdocument?

Tags: javascript, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have the following schema and subschema:

The child schema:

```
const SettingSchema = new Schema({
   settingIdentifier: {
      type: String,
      required: true
   },
   shareLink: {
      type: String,
      required: true
   },
   downloadLink: {
      type: String,
      required: true
   },
   direction: {
      type: String,
      required: true
   }

});
```

And the parent schema:

```
const DeviceSchema = new Schema({
    id: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    store: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    storeName: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    deviceInfo: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    },
    contentSettings:{
      type:[SettingSchema],
      required: true
    }
})
```

In my code, I want to get the child schema name from the retrieved document.
For example, I can get the document as such:

```
Device.findOne({ deviceInfo: "someValue" }).then(device => {
    // device is the retrieved document
    // with this device object, how do I get the device[settings] schema name?
    // device[settings] is an array of SettingSchema with possibly multiple members
    // Expected output : "SettingSchema"
});
```

So, how do I get the schema name of the subdocument "settings" when I have the "device" object?

Many thanks in advance.

Edit:
I'm attaching the console.log to show what device contains after Device.findOne.

```
{
        "_id": "5ea034d07d865e38c0d4ed6f",
        "id": "1a89d59800a72e39",
        "store": 1,
        "storeName": "Singapore Store",
        "deviceInfo": "test device2",
        "contentSettings": [
            {
                "settingIdentifier": "NewYearEvent",
                "shareLink": "share1",
                "downloadLink": "dl1",
                "direction": "D"
            },
            {
                "settingIdentifier": "EasterEvent",
                "shareLink": "share2",
                "downloadLink": "dl2",
                "direction": "H"
            }
        ],
        "__v": 0
    }
```

So Device.findOne gets a device instance from the database and it contains the data, but I don't see the metadata to identify the type or schema name of device itself, or its members

Comment: Can you console log device and show us the output

Comment: @AvivLo I edited the question with the output of "device". As mentioned, the device instance contains data from the database, but no metadata on the type or Schema name of itself or its members

Comment: Your schema is not giving us the whole story man. Your device schema has like 2 fields but your device object has like many. Could you please update your schema to the full one please.

Comment: @AvivLo I updated the schemas too, but it should be irrelevant. The actual implementation is of course, the schema and the device object matches perfectly.